# How do I tell Libvirt/QEMU/Virt-Manager 's new XML definition folder location?

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

Libvirt/QEMU/Virt-Manager normally do store the virtual machine's xml definition files in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/`.

The easiest way to change that would be to put that folder wherever you want (moved it to another partition), make a symlink/shortcut from there then replace the `/etc/libvirt/qemu/` folder with said symlink.

But you can't do that in fact, since `/etc/libvirt/qemu/` also has the `/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/` folder for no reasons at all, which Libvirt do forcibly needs at boot so it can find and enable the virtualized networks.

So, I don't have much choices other than to tell Libvirt where would the default xmls' definition folder be (I have tried to look that `/etc/libvirt/` configuration files, but nothing relevant there). How can I do that?

PS: I'm fine if there's a way to tell Libvirt the `networks/`'s folder new location, aka separating `/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/` from `/etc/libvirt/qemu/`.